# adding items in a shopping list (using javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a very basic shopping list using JavaScript - each time I click on "add item" I want to have that item and a button ("mark as bought") appear in the list.
I have written the following code but I can't figure it out why it is not working. Right now if I add an item and submit, I only have the table row "Item Description and Action" showing up. Also, there are no errors showing up in my console.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
Ioana

```js
var items = []; 

function deseneazaTabel(){
    if (items.length === 0){
        document.getElementById("list").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("list").style.display = "";
    }
    var str = ""; 
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        str += `<tr>
                <td>${items[i].name}</td>
                <td><button>Mark as bought</button></td>
                </tr>`;
    }
    document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML = str;
}

function addItem(form, event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var item = {}; 
    var input = form.querySelectorAll("input[name]"); 
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++ ){
        var a = input[i].getAttribute("name");
        var v = input[i].value; 
        item[a] = v; 
    }
    document.getElementById("list").classList.remove("hidden");
    deseneazaTabel(); 
}
```

```html
<body onload = "deseneazaTabel();">
  <h1 class="centerText bold">SHOPPING LIST</h1>
  <form class="centerText" onsubmit="addItem(this,event);">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" class="addBtn" value="Add item">
  </form>
  <p class="centerText sortButtons">
      <button class="sort">Sort asc</button>
      <button class="sort">Sort desc</button>
  </p>
  <div id="list" class="centerText hidden">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td>Item Description</td>
                  <td id="cellspaced">Action</td>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are indeed errors currently - press "Run code snippet", try to fix the current syntax errors

Comment: Add item is not working in your code, Please correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issue in the *for* loop inside *addItem()*.

1. You have to check the *length* property of *input* variable instead of *item*.
2. You also have to push the *item* object to the *items* array:

Your for loop should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
  var a = input[i].getAttribute("name");
  var v = input[i].value; 
  item[a] = v; 
  items.push(item);
}
```

```js
var items = []; 

function deseneazaTabel(){
  if (items.length === 0){
      document.getElementById("list").style.display = "none";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("list").style.display = "";
  }
  var str = ""; 
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
      str += `<tr>
              <td>${items[i].name}</td>
              <td><button>Mark as bought</button></td>
              </tr>`;
  }
  document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML = str;
  
}

function addItem(form, event){
  var item = {}; 
  var input = form.querySelectorAll("input[name]"); 
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
      var a = input[i].getAttribute("name");
      var v = input[i].value; 
      item[a] = v; 
      items.push(item);
  }
  document.getElementById("list").classList.remove("hidden");
  deseneazaTabel(); 
  event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

```html
<body onload = "deseneazaTabel();">
  <h1 class="centerText bold">SHOPPING LIST</h1>
  <form class="centerText" onsubmit="addItem(this,event);">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" class="addBtn" value="Add item">
  </form>
  <p class="centerText sortButtons">
      <button class="sort">Sort asc</button>
      <button class="sort">Sort desc</button>
  </p>
  <div id="list" class="centerText hidden">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td>Item Description</td>
                  <td id="cellspaced">Action</td>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</body>
```